# Angular change detection with ngFor and Map

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I have a problem with the change detection of Angular 11 in this case:

I have a map and iterate it in the template using the keyvalues pipe and an additional callback to get the original order of the map and not orderd by key.

But when I change this map the change detection does nothing.

I know that the keyvalues pipe generates a complete new array. So it is clear, that changing references in the map will not trigger the change detection.
But why not on changing the complete Map?

Here is some code:

Template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let postMap of mappingMap.events | keyvalue: originalOrder; let i = index">
   <ion-slide *ngIf="!postMap.value.isHiddenByFilter" (click)="showSlideActionSheet('events', postMap.key)" class="overview-slide" >
```

Component:

```
    interface MappingMapvalue {
        isHiddenByFilter: boolean;
        sliderIndex: number;
    }
    
    mappingMap: Map<number, MappingMapvalue>;
    
    pseudyfunction(cpt: string): void {
        let newMap: any;
        posts: ....................
    
        newMap = [...this.mappingMap[cpt].entries()].sort((a, b) =>
                posts[a[0]][key].toLowerCase() > posts[b[0]][key].toLowerCase()
                ? 1
                : posts[b[0]][key].toLowerCase() > posts[a[0]][key].toLowerCase() ? -1 : 0
            );
    
        
        this.mappingMap[cpt] = new Map(newMap); // Why no change detection here? This is a complete new Map! Same properties but another order
        
    
    }

originalOrder = (a: KeyValue<number,MappingMapvalue>, b: KeyValue<number,MappingMapvalue>): number => 0;
```

Is anyone able to ecplain why the change detectin does not trigger when the map is new initialized?

The change detection triggers, if I do this:

```
const newMap2 = new Map();
newMap2.set(700, {isHiddenByFilter: true, sliderIndex: 0});
this.mappingMap[cpt] = newMap2;
```

But why then and not on changing the complete map?

An additional question is:

This does not trigger change detection:

```
this.mappingMap[cpt] = new Map(newMap);
            this.mappingMap[cpt].set('newdummyfield', {isHiddenByFilter: true, sliderIndex: undefined});
            this.mappingMap[cpt].delete('newdummyfield');
```

But this triggers it:
(This does not make sense in scenario, but I wanted to test it)

```
this.mappingMap[cpt] = new Map(newMap);
            this.mappingMap[cpt].set('newdummyfield', {isHiddenByFilter: true, sliderIndex: undefined});
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.mappingMap[cpt].delete('newdummyfield');
            });
```

Does the change detection wait for the complete synchronous code? Is this the usual behaviour of the change detection?

Comment: Do you have onPush? have you tried with `markForCheck()`? I wouldn't rely on those methods to call change detections.

Comment: Change detection doesn't run when you use a pipe, unless the value that is to be piped has changed. So, unless `mappingMap.events` changes, change detection won't run.

Comment: @Get Off My Lawn As you can see in my question above I asked exactly this: "Is anyone able to explain why the change detectin does not trigger when the map is new initialized?" It is a complete new map an nothing is triggert

Comment: @Bojan Kogoj I do not use onPush and I did not try markForCheck. But I think the change detection has to run if I create the mappingMap.events completely new with new Map().

Comment: It doesn't matter that it is a new map. Your pipe is on `events` so unless `events` changes no detection will be triggered.

Comment: But events is the new Map and it is new and it has changed. You can see it in the code above. in "this.mappingMap[cpt]" cpt is "events"